# Norton Ghost : why do I need so much disk space to run backup?

Tags: norton-ghost

I made an image (31GB) of my freshly installed Windows 7 on my C:/ partition a few months ago. Today my Windows is slow so I want to put my image. I suppose it's all about reading (the image) and writing it over whatever there is on my C:/, yet Ghost asks tons of disk space for the operation.

Why is that ? Why disk space is needed just for reading and writing ?

Edit: my image size is 31GB and is currently stored on a partition having 3GB free space, my C partition size is 80GB, my Ghost version is 15.0. To restore the image I clicked on "Run or Manage Backups", selected my image and click on "Run Now".

Comment: We need more information, partition layout, and exactly how you are attempting to restore the image, version of Ghost, etc.

Comment: You said it’s asking for too much; ***how** much* is it asking for? Moreover, **what’s** asking for too much space; the backup command or the restore command?

Answer (score 1):

Although you only had 31GB of data, Ghost took an image of the entire partition.  The partition is 80GB, even though there is only 31GB of data.  When restoring, it will lay down the 80GB partition, which includes 31GB data and 49GB of empty space.